# Computing coefficients of theta functions associated to quadratic forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity, modular-forms, quadratic-forms, computational-number-theory

If we take an integral positive definite quadratic form $Q$ and set $\Theta_Q(z) = \sum_{k\geq 0}R_Q(k)e^{2\pi ikz}$, what are the most efficient algorithms to compute the $R_Q(k)$? I am aware e.g. of the results in Edixhoven et al's [book](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605244v3), for even unimodular lattices (Theorem 15.3.2); but are these the current state of the art? (Assuming GRH is fine).

Comment: Peter Bruin has extended the algorithms to allow modular forms of any level (hence quadratic forms which are not necessarily even unimodular). See this paper from 2011: https://doi.org/10.5802/pmb.a-133

Comment: Why involve the theta series?  You can just formulate your question as one about computing representation numbers.

Comment: @Kimball The algorithms of Edixhoven et al rely fundamentally on the modularity of $\Theta_Q$. Do you know an algorithm which doesn't use the modular interpretation, and which is competitive in complexity with their algorithm? (I certainly don't.) So calling for all mention of $\Theta_Q$ to be struck out of the question would seem a strange, almost Luddite approach.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler No, but the OP doesn't describe Edixhoven's algorithm at all.  With the information that is in the question, I just thought the question be stated more directly without theta series.  (That said, I would prefer if the OP gave more background.)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler that reference is great - thanks so much!